# More ions form pairs when concentration of acid increases, does that decrease the speed of reaction?

Tags: acid-base, electrochemistry, aqueous-solution, concentration

Electrical conductivity decreases as an acid becomes more concentrated because more ions form pairs. However, does that affect the speed of reaction of the acid as there is a smaller concentration of Hydrogen ions?

Comment: Considering H3O+ activity coefficient steeply raises for high acid concentrations, it is the opposite.

Answer (score 1):

In general, the conductivity of any liquid increases with the concentrations of its ions, and decreases with their dimensions. In pure sulfuric acid, the only ions existing are $\ce{H3SO4+}$ and $\ce{HSO4-}$. They are big and their concentration is low. So the conductivity of pure sulfuric acid is low. But when you add some water, the $\ce{H2O}$ molecules are totally transformed into $\ce{H3O+}$ and $\ce{HSO4-}$ ions which are numerous and sometimes small (for $\ce{H3O+}$). The conductivity must increase.

Comment: Does this affect the number/concentration of H3O+ ions available for acid reactions?